# Spark - not getting a int from a value of a map in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a object that is defined as

```
pLinkGroupsByP: Map[String, Set[(String, Int)]]
```

I am trying to get Int in the object to be returned if it exists otherwise return `0` thus the `.getOrElse(0)`

```
val result:Int =
  Try{
    pLinkGroupsByP(Doc.productType.id)
      .contains(Doc.Group.id,container.containerDoc.GroupOrder)
       (Doc.Group.id,container.containerDoc.GroupOrder)._2
  }.getOrElse(0)
```

- `(Doc.productType.id)` is to access the **key**
- `(Doc.Group.id)` is to access the value **1st** part of the **value**
- `(container.containerDoc.GroupOrder)` is to access the 2nd part of value which is what I need to be assigned to result.

However, I am getting only the first number of the first value in the map no matter what. I just need the number in the value to be assigned back to the result in this try statement.

Sample data is

```
Map["pro-ucw32, Set[(PRD-1292, 5)]]
```

Comment: So, either your data all are 0, or you have an exception.

Comment: @Marcin i got past the zero, now after i add this
`(Doc.Group.id,container.containerDoc.GroupOrder)._2`
It will give me back the number however, only the first number of the value.
i.e it only gives me back `7` even for `3008` even thought its supposed to be `5`. please take a look at the pic of sample data

Comment: @dedpo Can you please include the declaration of Doc? Thanks

Comment: Have you considered just simplifying your data structure, and using a simple map with a compound key, and the int as the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 val tupleToMap = pLinkGroupsByP(Doc.productType.id).toMap
    tupleToMap(relatedDoc.lkGroup.id).GetorElse(0)
```

The tuple to map converts value is assigned a tuple to map,

```
relatedDoc.linkGroup.id is a key being mapped and retunred if its a number greater than 1 it will be returned and then a 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can get the result with simple if else

```
val result:Int = if(pLinkGroupsByP(Doc.productType.id).contains(Doc.Group.id,container.containerDoc.GroupOrder)) container.containerDoc.GroupOrder else 0
```